# Sharing interactive posts from Google+ on Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm using the interactive post feature from Google+, but it's being blocked

- Claimed origin not in whitelist: https://googledrive.com
- Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

My Google APIs Console is using the URL from the website as JavaScript origin, all there looks right.

https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts

Thanks.

Comment: This may be covered in the GDL presentation set for March 1st: https://plus.google.com/events/cikmapf6gg3prcacbe9qrgoqtks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Drive is available from multiple origins, you might be missing some of these possibilities from your APIs Console project, for example:

```
https://drive.google.com
http://drive.google.com
https://googledrive.com
https://www.googledrive.com
http://googledrive.com
http://www.googledrive.com
```

Each of those is considered a different origin. Plus depending on what you're doing, it could be on docs.google.com too.

Comment: And there's even more!  For interactive posts, I have seen it have issues where there is a missing trailing slash in origin. E.g. "http://drive.google.com/" can cause issues if the whitelisted page is "http://drive.google.com"