# Google+ Interactive posts closes with "Claimed origin not in whitelist" error

Tags: javascript, google-plus

The title says it all, really. I render the google+ button with js (code below) and there are no error or warnings. However, after user opens the interactive post dialog it closes and throws 'Claimed origin not in whitelist' error. It happens only on staging server, not on localhost.

Prior to asking here i found those threads: 
[Google+ API. Sharing interactive posts error. Claimed origin not in whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975326/google-api-sharing-interactive-posts-error-claimed-origin-not-in-whitelist) ,
[Sharing interactive posts from Google+ on Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139352/sharing-interactive-posts-from-google-on-google-drive) ,
[Google+ interactive post popup disappears after 0,5 sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730337/google-interactive-post-popup-disappears-after-0-5-sec) .

I am using urls with no trailing '/' and i'm using same link for content and calltoaction fields. This is code i render buttons with:

```
renderButton: ( options ) ->
  _defaultOptions =
    link: "http://staging.myapp.com"
    clientid: window.social_networks['googleplus'].appId
    prefilltext: 'Some text'
    cookiepolicy: 'none'
    calltoactionlabel: 'OPEN'
    calltoactionurl: "http://staging.myapp.com"
    contenturl: "http://staging.myapp.com"



  options = _.extend {}, _defaultOptions, options

  gapi.interactivepost.render options.container, options
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your staging URL setup as a Javascript Origin in the client ID for your project in the Google Developers Console: https://developers.google.com/console - this is the list that origins are checked against. Make sure the scheme matches - so you have https if accessing over https etc.